# Invalid Firebase path: .com. Firebase paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: android, firebase

I'm going to save the email and password in a Firebase database, but unfortunately I got this error.

```
Invalid Firebase path: .com. Firebase paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
```

[image]

Comment: The error message says it all, to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As could be noticed from the error, Firebase path(key) doesn't allow certain special characters in the path.
While storing email as path, I recommend you to encode the email i.e., replace 'dots' from 'commas'. If you wan't to retrieve, you can decode.

```
public static String EncodeString(String string) {
    return string.replace(".", ",");
}

public static String DecodeString(String string) {
    return string.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Let me know, how it goes for you.

**Update**

Using `UIDs` to store user details is better than `Email IDs`.

Comment: It working for me .thank you for ur answer

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. Please, mark the answer as accepted so that it can  help the other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

paths/look/like/this

youare.probably.confusing.them.with.urls.com

Check over the firebase documentation and your implementation and see where you may be using a url instead of a path.