# Android FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Get object reference and delete it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using FirebasaRecyclerAdapter in order to display a list of posts I got in my Firebase console. I want to get every post reference in order to be able to delete them. I already can get the url:

```
 public class PostAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = Post.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;

    public PostAdapter(Class<Post> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<PostViewHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref, Context context) {
        super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {
         String postReference = this.getRef(position).toString();
         viewHolder.bindPost(model, position, postReference);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

I get the string postReference and send it to my viewHolder. This viewHolder is the one I use to display my posts in the feed. When user clicks on the post, he can se the post details in another fragment (to which I send the postReference string:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("post", post);
bundle.putString("postReference", postReferece);

PostDetailFragment postDetailFragment = new PostDetailFragment();
postDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_enter, R.anim.slide_left_exit, R.anim.slide_right_enter, R.anim.slide_right_exit);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.feed_container, postDetailFragment, "PostDetailFragment").commit();
```

In the PostDetailFragment, I want to delete that post when delete button is clicked, so:

```
private View.OnClickListener deleteListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String postReference = bundle.getString("postReference");
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(postReference).removeValue();
        ((FeedActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
};
```

My problem is that Firebase doesn't accept my "postReference" string, it says:

```
Invalid Firebase Database path: https://(myapp).firebaseio.com/users/(userkey)/posts/KIJ999. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076398/invalid-firebase-path-com-firebase-paths-must-not-contain

Comment: I googled my problem before making this question. I obviously tried that because it is the very first link google gives us. It doesn't solve my problem and it is a waste of time for anyone who might get to this question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally got to solve this. When removing my post I need to use the post "path" which is not the URL I was getting so far. In order to get the path rather than the URL, I did:

```
@Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {

    String postUrl = this.getRef(position).toString();
    String postRoot = this.getRef(position).getRoot().toString();
    String postReference = postUrl.replace(postRoot,"");

    viewHolder.bindPost(model, position, postReference);
}
```

By doing that I remove the "https://(myapp).firebaseio.com" part of the URL (which is the part Firebase doesn't accept) and get the path to the post I want to remove.