# ListView OnItemClickListener using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Developing an app for books. On my home page, I would like a list of books, and the user to be able to click on one to bring it to the details page so they can purchase a book.

I have this working with a RecyclerView but I need to use a ListView here.

At the moment, when I click an item in the List, it crashes the app.

Here is my Home Page method to get all books and try to go to Details page:

```
public void getAllBooks(){
        mFirebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Book");
        mFirebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String id = ds.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                    String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                    String author = ds.child("author").getValue(String.class);
                    String category = ds.child("category").getValue(String.class);
                    String image = ds.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                    Double price = ds.child("price").getValue(Double.class);
                    Integer quantity = ds.child("quantity").getValue(Integer.class);
                    Integer noReviews = ds.child("noOfReviews").getValue(Integer.class);
                    Double rating = ds.child("rating").getValue(Double.class);

                    Book book = new Book(id, title, author, category, image, noReviews, quantity, price, rating);
                    allBooks.add(book);

                }
                booksAdapter = new ViewAllBooksAdapter(allBooks, CustomerWelcome.this);
                listView.setAdapter(booksAdapter);

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        ((GlobalVariables) CustomerWelcome.this.getApplication()).setCurrentBook(allBooks.get(position).toString());
                        startActivity(new Intent(CustomerWelcome.this, ViewBook.class));

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

My Adapter (in case its needed)

```
public class ViewAllBooksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Book> books;
int pos;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titleTV;
    TextView authorTV;
    TextView categoryTV;
    TextView priceTV;
    ImageView imageView;
}

public ViewAllBooksAdapter(ArrayList<Book> books, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.search_list_items, books);
    this.books = books;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_items, parent, false);
    viewHolder.titleTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleSearchItem);
    viewHolder.authorTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.authorSearchItem);
    viewHolder.categoryTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categorySearchItem);
    viewHolder.priceTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceSearchItem);
    viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookImage);

    viewHolder.titleTV.setText(books.get(position).getTitle());
    viewHolder.authorTV.setText(books.get(position).getAuthor());
    viewHolder.categoryTV.setText(books.get(position).getCategory());
    viewHolder.priceTV.setText("€ " + books.get(position).getPrice().toString());

    Picasso.with(context).load(books.get(position).getImage()).fit().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(viewHolder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}
```

My global variable class also:

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Application{

    String currentBook;

    public String getCurrentBook() {
        return currentBook;
    }

    public void setCurrentBook(String currentBook) {
        this.currentBook = currentBook;
    }
}
```

As always, any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** My error:

```
 Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: com.example.cf.bookapplication.entity.Book@9c83686. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqh.zzjm(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.example.cf.bookapplication.activity.ViewBook.onCreate(ViewBook.java:152)
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque my app crashes if I click something in the list

Comment: Share the error you got

Comment: What is the error? Did you check if it crashes before it gets in the onClick or while in the onClick block? If it crashes after, did you reference your ViewBook activity in your manifest?

Comment: Please share your error log. Without that we will not be able to help you.

Comment: @MatthieuMeunier shared my error there

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076398/invalid-firebase-path-com-firebase-paths-must-not-contain

Comment: Issue is happening in `ViewBook` class line no `152` and you need to do something like this as a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/41077295/3111083 .

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi why did you put that up?

Comment: @ChloeFinn share your Firebase Node Structure.!